# What's this flowing river sound from under my back seat?

Tags: leak, noise

I turned the engine on. Then heard a flowing river under the back seats, towards the middle. It sounds like when you are pouring water out of a bottle, or when a small stream is moving through rocks. I turned the engine off and the sound went off ten seconds after. Thought it could be the coolant, but can't figure out why does it sound from under the back seat

Comment: Hi, welcome to the community :) What make, model and year of car do you have?

Comment: I would guess you have a small hole in the exhaust pipe. When it grows into a big hole and the noise gets louder, it will be more obvious what is wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the fuel pump/fuel through lines to me. Do you get the sound when you turn your key to the engine on position without going to the next click to actually start the motor?